# Magento - FishPig Integration - Not getting correct template for /blog

Tags: magento

- I have installed fresh version of WP, and Fish Pig and Magento.
- My website is not showing the template when I click on blog.

www.lawsongems.com/blog where it should have template as shown here www.lawsongems.com

It seems to be grabbing stylesheets from here

When I think it should be skin/frontend/gravdept/acumen/css (Which is the theme I'm using.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In magento, you need to change package which you create.

System->Configuration->General->design

Write your folder name in package and Theam.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have either the "Wordpress URL" or the "Blog URL" defined wrong in your WP-backend.

Refer to this documentation: http://fishpig.co.uk/wordpress-integration/docs/installation-and-configuration.html

Else: is it fully or semi-integrated? And: is the WP-folder inside or outside /magento/-folder?

Cheerz
Simon