# Fishpig's Magento WP Integration -- WP not using Magento Theme/Package

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I've successfully installed Fishpig's Magento WordPress Integration extension. I followed the instructions where you install via Magento Connect and had no problems. This is by the way all on the development server which does not have Caching or Compiling enabled.

The Magento cart is installed in the webroot directory and WordPress is in subdirectory "wp" as stated in Fishpig's instructions. The Full Integration blog path is /blog.

**PROBLEM:**

When I visit the blog's page it is not using the Magento theme. I even set it to use the same layout (same as CMS's homepage) We have a custom Magento theme. Maybe there is something we are doing incorrectly Magento theme wise for Fishpig's extension not to work. Screenshots to come eventually but the host (DataGram) is down due to the flooding Downtown. Should be back hopefully today.

To clarify... WordPress is using its own database. In the Shop's admin panel->WordPress tab I setup Full Integration and set the path to "wp" and the blog path is blog.

So, now if I visit for example... example.com you are in the shop and if you visit example.com/blog you are in the fully integrated blog.

Bottom line is it seems to be configured fine in the admin panel. I am not requesting the blog page from the wp directory (I.E: example.com/wp) but from the fully integrated page (example.com/blog).

**Our problem could be similar to what this person is experiencing:**

[Magento - FishPig Integration - Not getting correct template for /blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888221/magento-fishpig-integration-not-getting-correct-template-for-blog)

Have a great weekend all!

Best Regards,

George

Comment: may i know, where can i download the FishPig Integration? could You give me a link or something?

Comment: Can be obtained @ http://fishpig.co.uk/wordpress-integration.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huzzah looks like I got things working :-)

The culprit was that this file:

```
"app/design/frontend/default/eboost/layout/wordpress.xml"
```

^^ was pointing to the wrong template filename. Corrected and was good to go. Modified line was number 66.

**Funny thing is that on the top of that XML file it states:**

"

- Option 1 - local.xml (recommended)
- Create a file named local.xml in your custom theme's layout folder. You can then make changes to the layout there by
- using the relevant layout handle. This allows you to leave this file intact and recieve new features
- when upgrading the extension.
- Option 2 - copy this file
- Copy this file and it's contents to a new file in your custom theme's layout folder named wordpress.xml.
- Each time you upgrade, you will need to check with your copy of the file and
- the copy in app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/wordpress.xml for changes and merge any you find"

Now, as stated in my Original Posting I installed FishPig extension using their instructions: http://fishpig.co.uk/wordpress-integration/docs/installation-and-configuration.html

^^ Therefore I don't know why it is setup using Option 2. That wordpress.xml is in our theme's layout directory.

.

.

.

I feel I should also state the other changes I did even though it doesn't seem like it contributed to making it work. Just doing for completeness:

-- Renamed the subdirectory /wp to /wordpress and changed all references to dev.eboost.com/wp to dev.eboost.com/wordpress within the DataBase using http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

-- Removed .htaccess from /wordpress folder

So bottom line is looks like it is working normally. We are now set for working on redesign for site.

--George

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this.
http://www.wellicious.com/gbren/wellblog

I also used Fishpig and it is working.

What do you mean by visiting the blog page? Do you request the blog page from the wordpress directory?
If so, it doesn't change its design.

You have to request the blog within your shop.

Comment: So, your integrated WordPress blog is using your Magento Theme? Any design changes that occur to your Magento Theme are also reflected on your blog correct?

Comment: Removed my last comment as the line breaks did not work and added them to my OP. It does not work just yet.

Comment: Finally got back around to working on this. We will need WP integrated with Magento for next redesign.

Here is Magento which is fine:
https://dev.eboost.com/

Here is WP on the fully integrated link:
https://dev.eboost.com/blog

I get all smiles on the FishPig WP setup area so I don't get it. My theme I think is fine. Maybe if we connect via Skype I can share my screen and go over it? My Skype name is kc2keo.